can two lovers (not dating but waiting for marrage) go hangout with each other/ go on dates
So I like this girl and she like me back and we have the intentions of getting married and are not dating/not in a haram relationship but cant get married YET as we are only 16
so the question is can we go hangout in public places with appropriate talk and not touch each other

No.
The two persons are non-mahrams to each other. They may look at each other with the intention of deciding on whether to send or accept a proposal for marriage. But from the question this clearly does not seem to be the intention as it states that they can not yet get married.
Until they marry they are like any other non-mahram and need to observe all relevant laws such as not looking at each other and observing segregation and hijab. Just having the intention to marry does not somehow waive Islamic laws.
Indeed the need for observing them is even greater in this case since it is known that there is attraction between the two and hence there exists temptation to do something haram and when you look at her it is accompanied by desire.
In Islam you are told to not even go near to Zina:

ولا تقربوا الزنا
Do not even go close to fornication
— Quran 17:32

While you are going near it by hanging out with someone to whom you are attracted, which will make it easier to commit zina.
In Islam non-mahrams should not talk with each other without necessity:

ذهب الفقهاء إلى أنه لا يجوز التكلم مع الشابة الأجنبية بلا حاجة لأنه مظنة الفتنة
The view of the scholars is that it is not permissible to speak with a non-mahram young woman without necessity, due to risk of fitnah
— Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah

You can however do Nikah and then do whatever you wish afterwards, there is no age restriction for that in Islam.
